# I want to merge two PostScript Documents, pagewise. How?

Tags: pdf-generation, postscript

i have a tricky question, so i need to describe my problem:
i need to print 2-sided booklets (a third of a paper) on normal paper (german A4, but letter is okay also) and cut the paper afterwards.

The Pages are in a Postscript Level 2 File (generated by an ancient printer driver, so no chance to patch that, except ps2ps) generated by me with the ancient OS's Printing driver facilities (GpiMove, GpiLine, GpiText etc).

I do not want to throw away two-thirds of the paper, so my idea is: Take file one, two and three, merge them (how?) on new double-sided papers by translate/move file two and three by one resp. two thirds and print the resulting new pages.

If it helps, I can manage to print one page of the booklet per file.

I cannot "speak" postscript natively, but I am capable of parsing and merging and manipulating files programmaticly. Maybe you can hint me to a webpage. I've read through the manuals on adobe's site and followed the links on www.inkguides.com/postscript.asp

Maybe there are techniques with PDF that would help? I can translate ps2pdf.

Thanks for help
Peter Miehle

PS:
my current solution: i.e. 8 pages: print page 1, 4 and 7 on page one, 2,5,8 on page two and 3,6,blank on page three, cut the paper and restack. But i want to use a electrical cutting machine, which works better with thicker stacks of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try psbook or psnup. For instance, at http://www.tardis.ed.ac.uk/~ajcd/psutils/